# How to use "Seemed like (something) had not (something)"

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, bare-conditional, reversed-conditional

I found the following sentence in *Marguerite de Valois* by Alexandre Dumas

> His body seemed like that of a corpse had not a light breath stirred
>   the fringe of foam on the lips.

It looks like a conditional sentence but it doesn't have would/if.

I would appreciate very much any information about this use of "had not".
I used a similar pattern in the following sentence, is it correct?

> The sculpture's wings seemed real had not been made of stone

Comment: This sentence does not seem grammatical to me. A similar construction would make sense to me: *His body would have seemed like that of a corpse, had not a light breath stirred the fringe of foam on his lips.* In this case, it means *had it not been the case*.

Comment: It's olde stuff.  Insert a comma after "corpse".

Comment: The second sentence would not be considered correct, even to the guy who translated Dumas's work.

Comment: @MikeGraham If the sentence had been written in English originally rather than being translated from French I suspect that it would have been "His body _would have_ seemed like a corpse...".  Even for 19C English and with the comma inserted the actual construction seems a bit odd.

Comment: @ Hot Licks You're on *fire* tonight.

Comment: *were it not made of stone* would be (at least) better style imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This conditional usage of **had** doesn't need any ifs or woulds.

> Death had been sweet today three years ago
>   - *MacGregor's translation of Petrarch's Sonnet X.*
>
> Death had been sweet from thy hand
>   - *The Blue Bird, The Fairy Tales of the Countess d'Aulnoy, 1856*
>
> .....................................or that she would of late
>     Have taught to ignorant men most violent ways,
>   [...] Had they but courage equal to desire.
>   - *No Second Troy by William Butler Yeats, 1921*

As Hot Licks sort of says, it's quite old-fashioned. I'm not sure why you would want to use it! No - your sentence isn't quite right. It needs an 'it':

**The sculpture's wings seemed real had it not been made of stone.**

Remember it's not present-day English. We would say, 'The sculpture's wings would/might have seemed real if they hadn't been made of stone.'

Comment: Thank you so much Old Brixtonian :D